# Match question, alternatives and put them into variables PHP - /^(?:a\))(?:b\))(?:c\))(?:d\))(?:e\))/

Tags: php, regex

I have a question with alternatives like this:

```
What is your favorite product? 
a) product 1 
b) product 2 
c) product 3 
d) product 4 
e) product 5
```

I'd like to MATCH que question (it always the first thing in text) and alternatives (they start with a) b) c) d) or e))

SO, I'd like to scan the text and put each part in variables:

IN THE EXAMPLE ABOVE:

```
$question = will receive "What is your favorite product?"
$answer_a = "a) product 1"
$answer_b = "b) product 2"
$answer_c = "c) product 3"
$answer_d = "d) product 4"
$answer_e = "e) product 5"
```

I tried this, but no success to separate. I'd like to store the right alternative in the right variable.

```
    <?php

    $text = "What is your favorite product?
a) product 1
b) product 2
c) product 3
d) product 4
e) product 5"

    $re = '/^(?:a\))(?:b\))(?:c\))(?:d\))(?:e\))/';

    if (preg_match($re, $text)) {
        echo $re; // ???? and regex not getting question until a)
    }
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because the question may have some breaklines. and maybe some alternative, inside a), for example, if it is a long text it may have a breakline. So I think it is better to get from the start till a) then from a) till b)...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Array ( [0] => What is your favorite product? [1] => a) product 1 [2] => b) product 2 [3] => c) product 3 [4] => d) product 4 [5] => e) product 5 )

Comment: Can you split on `\R(?=[a-e]\))` like [this](https://tio.run/##Rc1NCsIwEEDh/ZxiFoUkoBT/VrXkDm5cWCmxjSagZpikgqeP2UiWHzx45CjnoyZHAE3EHsXZmYQ@4jcsjHfzCeyTReIwL1PSCEb9gRuEW9UWYaraIcxVewRbdRBduXG5EdvHGOnpkxTtcJK6v5i1vQ5KtS@xaqIqIbF/p5Flw6rL@Qc)?

Comment: @ctwheels oh, it seems nice!  the last answer bug ;/ `Array ( [0] => What is your favorite product? [1] => a) product 1 [2] => b) product 2 [3] => c) product 3 [4] => d) product 4 [5] => e) product 5 )` it ended with an `)` know why?

Comment: That's the array's closing parenthesis.

Comment: @ctwheels oh, sorry! so it worked!! :) thanks very much.

Comment: No problem, I converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex with `preg_split`:

```
\R(?=[a-e]\))
```

How it works:

- `\R` matches Unicode newline character (`\r\n` or `\r` or `\n` aka `CR LF` or `CR` or `LF`)
- `(?=[a-e]\))` positive lookahead ensuring the following matches

  - `[a-e]` matches a character in the set (one of `abcde`)
  - `\)` matches `)` literally

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##Rc1NCsIwEEDh/ZxiFoUkoBT/Vm3JHdy4sFJiG01AzDBJBU8fs5EsP3jwyFHOvSZHAE3EAcXFmYQ@4jesjA/zCeyTReKwrHPSCEb9gTuEe9UeYa46ICxVRwRbdRJduXG5EdvnFOnlkxTteJZ6uJqtvY1KtWLTRFU6Yv9OE8uGVZfzDw)

```
<?php

$s = 'What is your favorite product? 
a) product 1 
b) product 2 
c) product 3 
d) product 4 
e) product 5';

$r = preg_split('/\R(?=[a-e]\))/',$s);

print_r($r);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => What is your favorite product? 
    [1] => a) product 1 
    [2] => b) product 2 
    [3] => c) product 3 
    [4] => d) product 4 
    [5] => e) product 5
)
```